# How to convert a utf-8 string to a utf-16 string in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, utf-16

How do I convert a utf-8 string to a utf-16 string in PHP?

Answer (score 14):

mbstring [supports UTF-16](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), so you can use [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

It's native in PHP, but require that all your text is one charset. Else it could discard characters.