# Convert a utf-8 string to UTF16 entities in PHP

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php

$message = "ΓΙΑ ΝΑ ΔΟΥΜΕ ΤΙ ΘΑ ΔΟΥΜΕ.";
$tmp = mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-16BE', 'utf-8');
echo $tmp;
?>
```

The $message value holds some Greek words. I want to have something like this "0393 0399 0391 0020 039D 0391 0020 0394 039F 03A5 039C 0395 0020 03A4 0399 0020 0398 0391 0020 0394 039F 03A5 039C 0395" but instead I get some black diamonds with question marks in the browser.

I tried to follow those instructions ([Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155514/how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-to-a-utf-16-string-in-php)) but with no luck. I also tried to change the encoding of the file from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without BOM, but again no luck.

While searching I found this amazing webpage [Unicode Code Converter](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) so I could test if I was getting the right entities.

Comment: What exacly do you want to do? Just return `0393 0399 0391 0020 039D 0391` ?

Comment: perhaps there's different charsets of the file and the string. print the string in notepad++ and the change the charset of the string by go to "Encoding" and then select the prefered charset to convert to

Comment: Yes. I want to get  Hexadecimal code points out of any string.

Comment: I also said this. I changed the file encoding to notepad ++ and made sure it was utf-8. The string is utf-8, there is no need to change it to anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json_encode()` to extract hexadecimal code:

```
echo strtoupper(str_replace(array('"', '\u'), array('',' '), json_encode('ΓΙΑ ΝΑ ΔΟΥΜΕ ΤΙ ΘΑ ΔΟΥΜΕ.')));
//  0393 0399 0391  039D 0391  0394 039F 03A5 039C 0395  03A4 0399  0398 0391  0394 039F 03A5 039C 0395.
```

This works for any language.

Comment: Amazing :-) Exactly the result I wanted. Mihai I am searching for hours...and the answer was one line of code? Damn feel like a huge looser...

Comment: Yes I know :) `JSON` saved me too many times when I had encoding issues for unicode characters. It never fails :)

Comment: Hm.. when I have Latin or special characters it doesn't work :-( .Example "ΓΙΑ ΝΑ ΔΟΥΜΕ ;!This is a TEST"

Comment: @GeorgeD., everyone read your question, reediting it and unaccepted the correct answer is wrong. You should start a new question. My answer was 100% accurate with main question.

Comment: I am really sorry about that. Your answer was fine, my question wasn't clear enough. I'll resubmit it.

Answer (score 1):

the mbstring supports UTF-16 you can use the  `mb_convert_encoding`.

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "utf-8", "UTF-16BE");
```

Comment: `string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding ] )`