# Javascript to PHP domain.charCodeAt(i)

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to convert a javascript snippet into PHP.
Javascript is

```
var sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
for (var i = domain.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sum1 += domain.charCodeAt(i) * 13748600747;
    sum2 += domain.charCodeAt(i) * 40216416130;
}

var x = ("$" + sum1).substring(0, 8) + ("" + sum2).substring(0, 8);
```

But couldn't understand this part, `sum1 += domain.charCodeAt(i) * 13748600747;` I mean which PHP function can be used instead of domain.charCodeAt(i).

**EDIT:**

My PHP code:

```
$domain = "example.com";
$sum1 = 0;
$sum2 = 0;
$length = strlen($domain);
$i = $length - 1;
for ( $i; $i >= 0; $i-- ) {
    $sum1 += ord($domain[$i]) * 13748600747;
    $sum2 += ord($domain[$i]) * 40216416130;
}
$newsum = "$".$sum1;
$x = substr($newsum,0,8) + substr($sum2,0,8);

echo $x;
```

Output is definitely different. Need Help.

Comment: Note: JavaScript strings are stored as [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) codes. For the equivalent in PHP, http://stackoverflow.com/q/155514 may help.

Comment: Regarding your edit, you just have a typo. `+` should be `.` -- `$x = substr($newsum,0,8) . substr($sum2,0,8);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a Unicode safe version.

```
$domain = "example.com";
$sum1 = 0;
$sum2 = 0;

// this will convert $domain to a UTF-16 string,
// without specifying the third parameter, PHP will
// assume the string uses PHP's internal encoding,
// you might want to explicitly set the `from_encoding`
$domain = mb_convert_encoding($domain, 'UTF-16');

$length = mb_strlen($domain, 'UTF-16');
$i = $length - 1;

for ( $i; $i >= 0; $i-- ) {
    $char = mb_substr($domain, $i, 1, 'UTF-16');
    $sum1 += hexdec(bin2hex($char)) * 13748600747;
    $sum2 += hexdec(bin2hex($char)) * 40216416130;
}
$newsum = "$" . strval($sum1);
$sum2 = strval($sum2);
$x = substr($newsum,0,8) . substr($sum2,0,8);

echo $x;
```

The conversion to decimal is based of the code in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109724) on the [`ord` documentation](http://php.net/ord).

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, my PHP is a bit rusty and I'm not super-experienced with multi-byte code, but I think it should work. Anyone who knows better feel free to edit my answer to fix any obvious mistakes.

Comment: Updated 2 lines of codes and tested it. It works! This should be a better answer after my edit is accepted.

Comment: @NoviceCoder Without my 2-line-code-change being accepted, the above answer is not unicode safe.

Answer (score 3):

Because ord() only works for ascii but javascript uses utf-16, we'd better use

```
hexdec(bin2hex($utf16_char))
```

Here is the experiment I did:

```
// This is a utf8 character because my editor can only accept utf8
$utf8_char = "北";
// convert to utf16 using mb_convert_encoding()
$utf16_char = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_char, "utf-16", "utf-8");

// output is correct: int(21271), same as javascript output
var_dump(hexdec(bin2hex($utf16_char)));

// output is wrong: int(83) because ord() only works for ascii character.
var_dump(ord($utf16_char));
```

Note: in order to completely replace the above js code, you'd better use mbstring module and set utf-16 as the internal encoding.

```
mb_internal_encoding('utf-16');
```

Then use mb_* functions, e.g., use mb_strlen() instead of strlen(). Also you'd feed the php function with utf16 strings.

[**UPDATE**] To better understand the issue, note that the following 2 lines are equivalent:

```
hexdec(bin2hex($any_utf_char));
(int) base_convert(unpack("H*", $any_utf_char)[1], 16, 10); // Note: the array dereferencing only works in php5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be [`ord`](http://php.net/ord)`($domain[$i])`

Comment: Well, [`String.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) will work for all Unicode characters, while `ord()` will only work for a subset of Unicode (ASCII characters). That being said, I don't know what the fully compatible PHP version would be, this would've been my suggestion too.

Comment: Well, index-based access using `$domain[$i]` will fail before that - because it just returns a byte, whereas only the small ASCII-compatible part of Unicode uses only one byte to represent a character :-)